# How to uninstall Bitcoind from ubuntu server?

Tags: bitcoind, linux

I installed bitcoind on my ubuntu server awhile ago. How do I go about uninstalling it properly? Do i just delete the ~/.bitcoin folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed with a `deb` package, you can use apt-get to remove it:

```
sudo apt-get remove bitcoind
```

Comment: What if you installed according to the instructions?

Answer (score 1):

you will unistall bitcoin and the related folder by running the fellowing commands

```
rm -rf ~/.bitcoin

sudo apt-get remove bitcoind

sudo apt autoremove
```

Answer (score 0):

That will remove your `wallet.dat`, `bitcoin.conf` and all the `blockchain` info, but you will also want to remove the `bitcoin` directory which was also downloaded and if you added `bitcoind` to your path you'l want to remove that as well.